# Is there ruby syntax validation plugin for gedit?

Tags: gedit, plugins, ruby, rails

I am using the https://github.com/gmate/gmate setup, but it lacks a ruby syntax validation plugin.

Where can I find one?

Tnx!

Comment: not a real solution, but just to show that I'm fanatic, try using Vim! just kiddin' ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this is what your looking for but at least we can rule it out

[A repository for useful and handy snippets for gedit's external tools plugin](https://github.com/janlelis/gedit-external-tools)

Hope this helps

Comment: specifically this file: https://github.com/janlelis/gedit-external-tools/blob/master/ruby_check-syntax.rb